# How to create table dynamically based on #TempTableResult columns

Tags: sql-server

Im using pivot runtime and after running the same i want to store the result set in a table. so i need to create a table dynamically based on the result set. Any ideas?

Comment: If my answer is correct, please accept it by clicking the green tick near my answer! :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SELECT ... INTO` statement.
Example:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM #TempTableResult
```

This statement will create a new table called `NewTable` automatically based on the structure of `#TempTableResult` with all the data you get from the `SELECT`.

The columns of the `NewTable` will be the same as the output of the `SELECT` statement, with the same data types.

**EDIT**: Note that the `SELECT ... INTO` statement fails if the destination table already exists, so remember to drop it before running the query, or you may use a dynamically generated table name instead.